# How to have a div open by a button closed by clicking off when there are multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have several buttons on my site that call a script to open the content into full screen and I also want to be able to click off the created div to close it. This works but after opening one container, which is deleted after, my program produces errors trying to click another button.

```
function closeDiv(evt) {

        const maindiv = document.getElementById('div3');
        let targetElement = evt.target;

        do {
            if (targetElement == maindiv.childNodes[1]) {
                return;
            }

            targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;

        } while (targetElement);

        var viewpost = maindiv.childNodes[1];

        viewpost.parentNode.removeChild(viewpost);

        maindiv.classList.remove('viewcontainer');


    };




function buttonClick(button) {
    var div = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    var clone = div.cloneNode(true);

    var element = div.childNodes;

    var username = element[1].innerText;

    var title = element[7].innerText;

    var contenttext = div.childNodes[3].value;


    var clone = document.createElement('div');
    clone.classList.add('viewcontainercon');

    var viewuser = document.createElement('p');
    viewuser.classList.add('viewcontaineruser');
    var text = document.createTextNode(username);
    viewuser.appendChild(text);

    clone.appendChild(viewuser)
    var viewtitle = document.createElement('p');
    viewtitle.classList.add('viewcontainertitle');
    var text = document.createTextNode(title);
    viewtitle.appendChild(text);

    clone.appendChild(viewtitle);



    var viewcontent = document.createElement('p');
    viewcontent.classList.add('viewcontainercontent');
    var text = document.createTextNode(contenttext);
    viewcontent.appendChild(text);

    clone.appendChild(viewcontent);


    document.getElementById('div3').classList.add('viewcontainer');

    document.getElementById('div3').appendChild(clone);

    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var isClickInside = button.contains(event.target);

        if (!isClickInside) {
            closeDiv(event);
        }
    });


    }
```

The error is specifically `viewpost is undefined' in the closeDiv() function, which is strange since that shouldn't be called until after the click. Any ideas?

Comment: one way is to put another div behind the div being shown covering the full window, to suck up click events.

Comment: will try this thanks